# Строки. Проверка буква или нет

Tags: c, массивы, строки, проверка

Как исправить функцию, чтобы функция заменяла только слово, а не его часть (например, слово  "my" заменял на your, а my в "mydestiny" НЕ ЗАМЕНЯЛ). Я понимаю,что нужно сделать проверку перед и после слова стоит буква или не буква . Как раз 2 функция для этого. Но я не могу понять в какую строку вставлять 2 функцию, чтобы программа работала. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
     void Replace(char str[],char slovo1[],char slovo2[],char buffer[])
    {
        int i,j,pos=0;
        for(i=0;str[i];i++)
        {
            for(j=0;str[i+j]&&slovo1[j];j++)  
                if(str[i+j]!=slovo1[j]) break;
            if(!slovo1[j])  //если slovo1[j]=0, то мы дошли до конца строки slovo1
            {
                i+=j-1;  //в j у нас длина стоки slovo1, которую мы перепрыгиваем
                for(j=0;slovo2[j];j++) buffer[pos++]=slovo2[j];  //на место стоки slovo1 ставим slovo2
            }
            else
            {
                buffer[pos++]=str[i];   //просто копируем символ
            }
            buffer[pos]=NULL;  //ставим конец строки
        }
        strcpy(str,buffer);  //копируем в первоначальную строку
    }

    int main()
    {
        char str[100]="my destiny, not my destiny,mydestiny";
        char slovo1[]="my",slovo2[]="your";
        char buffer[200];
        Replace(str,slovo1,slovo2,buffer);
        printf("%s",str);
        return 0;
    }




//2 функция, кот. проверяет буква или нет
    int letterornot(char letter) {
    char l = tolower(letter);
    char a[] = "ёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
    if (a[i] == l)
    {
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да просто флаг сделай. Пока нет пробельного символа, слово не закончено. А раз не закончено, нефиг его сравнивать раньше времени.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον что такое флаг?

Comment: Флаг - просто переменная, которая сигнализирует о состоянии чего-либо. Флаги лучше всего делать с помощью перечислений (enum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// ищем слово word в строке str, начиная с позиции pos
int match(char str[], char word[], int pos) {
  // Если в строке есть предыдущие символы и это буква, выходим
  if (pos > 0 && letterornot(str[pos - 1]))
    return 0
  int len = 0;
  for (int i = 0; word[i] && str[pos + i]; i++) {
    if (word[i] != str[pos + i])
      return 0;
    // подсчитываем длину слова
    len++;
  }
  // если дошли сюда, то проверяем символ str[pos + len]
  // если он не буква, то возвращаем длину строки
  return (!letterornot(str[pos + len])) ? len : 0;
}

void Replace(char str[],char slovo1[],char slovo2[],char buffer[]) {
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    {
        int len = match(str, slovo, i);
        if(len)  //если нашли нужное слово
        {
            i += len;  //в len у нас длина стоки slovo1, которую мы перепрыгиваем
            for(j=0;slovo2[j];j++) buffer[pos++]=slovo2[j];  //на место стоки slovo1 ставим slovo2
        } else {
            buffer[pos++]=str[i];   //просто копируем символ
        }
        buffer[pos]=NULL;  //ставим конец строки
    }
    strcpy(str,buffer);  //копируем в первоначальную строку
}
```

Comment: спасибо, вы очень помогли. Подскажите, а что значит вот это: ? len : 0;

Comment: @NonaLolina [тернарный оператор](http://cppstudio.com/post/304/)

Comment: а вы не подскажите, как выделить замененное слово скобками?